# Pool de Conexiones Java

Tags: java

He realizado correctamente una conexión a un pool de conexiones, pero aun tengo la duda de como instanciar la clase conexión, mi pregunta es:

¿Cada vez que instancia la clase conexión se crea una nueva o se sobreescribe dicha conexión?

```
public ConexionPool(){
    inicializaDataSource();
}

private void inicializaDataSource(){
    I("<<<<<<<<<< Conexion Pool -----> "+db+" >>>>>>>>>");
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setUsername(user);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(pass);
    basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
    basicDataSource.setMaxActive(200);
    basicDataSource.setMinIdle(50);
    basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(100);
    dataSource = basicDataSource;
}
```

Como ven lo que obtiene la conexión es el `dataSource` pero no se si cada vez que se llama a la clase vuelve y se conecta y una configuración con 200 conexiones máximas mas o sobreescribe la configuración ya creada.

He establecido dos formas posibles en la clase conexión no se cual sea la mas correcta:

1. Llamar al método dentro del constructor:

   ```
   public ConexionPool(){
       inicializaDataSource();
   }

   private void inicializaDataSource(){
       I("<<<<<<<<<< Conexion Pool -----> "+db+" >>>>>>>>>");
       BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
       basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       basicDataSource.setUsername(user);
       basicDataSource.setPassword(pass);
       basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
       basicDataSource.setMaxActive(200);
       basicDataSource.setMinIdle(50);
       basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(100);
       dataSource = basicDataSource;
   }
   ```
2. Crear un método dentro de la clase conexión que me devuelve el `dataSource`:

   ```
   public DataSource SourceConnect(){
       if(this.dataSource==null){
           inicializaDataSource();
       }
       return this.dataSource;
   }
   ```

Comment: Por favor, comparte un [mcve]. El código actual es incompleto para entender bien tu pregunta.

Comment: en la pregunta deje la dos formas que se me ocurren para la inializacion de la conexion no se cual sea la mejor forma, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Cada vez que obtienes una conexión con `dataSource.getConnection()` el pool crea una nueva conexión **solamente si es necesario**, si tiene conexiones que actualmente no están en uso (idle), te devuelve una de estos. Por eso el pool mantiene una cantidad de conexiones listo para ser usado (minIdle-maxIdle).

**Importante** es de siempre llamar `connection.close()`, a las conexiones cuando terminaste usandolo. Eso en el caso de un pool **no** cierra la conexión, pero la devuelve al pool en estado *idle* para ser reutilizado.

Utilizando `BasicDataSource`ya tienes un pool de conexiones. La `BasicDataSource` implementa `PoolingDataSource` y en ser instada crea automáticamente un pool de conexiones por defecto. Así ni siquiera sería necesario de encapsularla aun más, solamente deberías asegurarte que usas la misma instancia con todos tus accesos.

En applicaciones en un *appserver* como *tomcat* por ejemplo eso se asegura en la manera que defines el datasource por defecto con xml. Sin framework, un servicio que se asegura de siempre devolver la misma fuente de datos sería un buen patrón.

```
public class DataSourceService{

    private static BasicDataSource basicDataSource=null;
    private String user = "username";
    private String pass = "password":

    public DataSourceService(){
         if (null==basicDataSource){
             basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
             basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             basicDataSource.setUsername(user);
             basicDataSource.setPassword(pass);
             basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
             basicDataSource.setMaxActive(200);
             basicDataSource.setMinIdle(50);
             basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(100);
         }
     }

     public BasicDataSource getDataSource(){
         return basicDataSource;
     }
```

Luego puedes simplemente desde tu código usar el servicio de obtener una conexión y usarla sin más consideraciones:

```
DataSourceService dss = new DataSourceService();
Connection con = dss.getDataSource().getConnection();
// trabajar con la conexión
//
con.close(); // devuelve la conexión a su pool
```

Una forma "correcta" no existe, eso es **una** forma que funciona, lo que importa es que la implementación esta clara y que te asegures que los conexiones se solicitan en la misma fuente de data.

Falta recomendarte de revisar los métodos `setValidationQuery(String query)`, `setTestOnBorrow(boolean testOnBorrow)` (si la fuente comprueba la conexión antes de pasarlo al mundo), `setTestOnReturn(boolean testOnReturn)` (si la fuente comprueba la conexión cuando se devuelve al pool) y `setTestWhileIdle(boolan testWhileIdle)` (comprueba las conexiones inactivas cuando se gestiona el pool de conexiónes *idle*).

Comment: en la pregunta deje la dos formas que se me ocurren para la inializacion de la conexion no se cual sea la mejor forma, gracias

Comment: Las gracias en SO se dan por votos y/o por aceptar la respuesta que te solucionó el problema. ;) Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en la experiencia, y observando el código que propones, probablemente una buena opción es crear la clase `ConexionPool` como un Singleton, y así poder adquirir una conexión a través de un método que encapsule el `dataSource.getConnection()`, el dataSource deberia ser miembro de la clase dicha clase, debería ser inicializada una sola vez y luego administrada hasta el cierre de la aplicación que debe desregistar todos sus recursos, `dataSource.close()`, ademas recordar cerrar cada conexión obtenida llamando el método  `close` de dicha conexión

Answer (score 0):

Hermano, creo que hay un enfoque erróneo

El pool, es un patrón, en general, que consiste de esta "bolsa" o Pool, de objetos de tipo "conexión a bd", esperando a ser utilizados, el pool es una lista de objetos.

¿Por qué existe el pool? el pool existe, como patrón de diseño cuando cierto objeto que se va a instanciar frecuentemente, tiene un costo de creación, tan alto que la creación de esta clase de objeto termina siendo lenta, o bien podría optimizarse sustancialmente.

El objeto de conexíón a la bd, es costoso como estructura en memoria enlazada a otros objetos que internamente le proveen ciertas rutinas, y además establece una conexión de red, en fin es un objeto relativamente costoso (en aplicaciones de alta concurrencia sí se nota).

Entonces se inventaron los pool de conexión, aplicando el patrón pool, para REUTILIZAR, instancias de este objeto, en la medida que van requiriendose.
Cuando usas objectos del tipo conexión **sin pool**, este se destruye y se crea, en el new, etc, pero si le creas **mediante el pool**, la primera vez se crea, y al terminar la transacción no se elimina de memoria, sino que se resetea o se limpia por encima lo suficiente para volver a atender la próxima petición.

Si existiendo, ya 1 objeto en el pool, y esta siendo utilizado, y llaman otros hilos pidiendo de estos objetos, si están siendo ocupados, los ya creados, ahí entonces el pool crea es decir **instancia** otro adicional en la pila, y si llegan más peticiones siempre el pool, primero busca una que ya terminó de trabajar lo limpia y lo entrega, pero cuando por concurrencia, se van creando más objetos, eventualmente podría llegarse al límite máximo. El mínimo es la cantidad por defecto al inicializar, lo relevante es el patrón que se aplica en objetos similares, por ejemplo, en servidores web, que atienden peticiones http, por ejemplo en tomcat-catalina como pool de objetos servlet.

Por tanto no debes redefinir el pool, en cada conexión, lo debes definir 1 sola vez, generalmente en configuración de infraestructura, pero también podrías hacerlo programáticamente como estás haciendo (no lo he hecho así y me parece interesante), pero sólo 1 vez. Luego el pool, provee conexiones a la aplicación para cuando ella solicite.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu colaboracion

Answer (score 0):

Por cierto la opción 2 es la mejor entre ambas opciones
Es la que además he visto en implementación, es muy aceptable

La 1 podría estar bien, si dejas claro dónde la vas a gatillar, ya que tendría que ejecutarse 1 sola vez, me queda esa duda dónde la estarías ubicando, si es un bean aplicativo podría ser, o en el arranque pero también depende de tu aplicación

La 2, setea el pool, 1 sola vez, en la primera petición, y eso implica que será 1 sola vez, en cierta forma es como un singleton, pero está el costo de que va estar preguntando si es igual a null, siempre, eso lo tienes que valorar dependiendo de tu app

===========================================================================

2, Crear un metodo dentro de la clase conexion que me duelve el dataSource

```
public DataSource SourceConnect(){
    if(this.dataSource==null){
        inicializaDataSource();
    }
    return this.dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no respondas mas de una vez a la misma pregunta, a menos que tengas una buena razón para ello.  Si deseas agregar más información a tu respuesta original, puedes usar el enlace `editar` debajo de la respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Un datasource por sí solo no consume conexiones a BD, si no que estas se consiguen al hacer `dataSource.getConnection();`.
Así, en respuesta a tu pregunta, al crear una Instancia de ConexionPool no se consumen conexiones.
Al instancia una clase Connection sí que se usan, y es el Datasource el encargado de su gestión, de forma que se puedan reutilizar. Tú simplemente llama a `dataSource.getConnection();` y deja el control en manos del Datasource.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, mi duda es como al instanciar la clase conexion el objeto DaraSource recibe nuevamente toda la configuración esta se reinicia o algo que  se mantiene intacta.
No se si dejar que en el constructor de la clase conexion llamar al metodo inicializaDataSource o  sino crear una método en dicha clase que me devuelva el datasource, no se si así también funcione y no me presente inconvenientes

Comment: Si cuelgas el código seguro que te damos ideas.

Comment: en la pregunta deje la dos formas que se me ocurren para la inializacion de la conexion no se cual sea la mejor forma, gracias

Comment: Yo crearía una clase ConexionPool con el datasource dentro, y accedería a él a través de un getDatasource() que llame a inicializaDataSource si es null (un singleton, vamos).

Comment: El error "Too many open connections" lo arroja el motor de base de datos si es que ya no puede crear más conexiones. El pool no lo arroja, y en ambiente de producción, lo más probable es que esto suceda solo si has configurado tu pool para 200 conexiones para todas las aplicaciones que usas (imagino por lo menos 2) y que la base de datos realmente esté exhausta.