# Problema al cerrar conexión bd java

Tags: java, mysql

He estado teniendo problemas con mi Java web application, después de unas horas no funciona nada y tira excepción de null, ya me dijeron que probablemente sea porque no cierro las conexiones a la bd MySql y se satura.

He intentado cerrar las conexiones, pero lo hago mal y me tira error de que después de cerrar la conexión no se puede hacer nada.

Tengo la clase conexion:

```
public class Conexion {

    private static Connection cnx = null;


    public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
       if (cnx == null) {
           try {
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               /*AMAZON*/  cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("CADENA CONEXIÓN A AMAZON Y USUARIO Y PASSW");
          } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             System.out.println("Clase Conexion: "+ex.getMessage());
          }
       }
       return cnx;
   }

    public static void cerrar() throws SQLException {
        if (cnx != null) {
            cnx.close();
       }
    }
}
```

Después tengo la clase Consulta, donde tengo todos los métodos de insertar, borrar, actualizar, etc.

```
public class Consulta {

    private final String tablas;
    private final String select;
    private final Connection cnx;

    public Consulta(String select, String tablas) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        this.select = select;
        this.tablas = tablas;
        this.cnx = Conexion.obtener();
    }

    public void insertar(String valores) throws SQLException{
        try{
            PreparedStatement stmt;
            stmt = cnx.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tablas + " VALUES(" + valores + ")");
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new SQLException(ex);
        }
    }

    public ResultSet recuperar(String condicion) throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            PreparedStatement stm = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT " + select + " FROM " + this.tablas + " WHERE " + condicion);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new SQLException(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public boolean actualizarPorId(int id, String cambio) throws SQLException{
        boolean func;
        try {
            func = false;
            PreparedStatement stmt = cnx.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + tablas + " SET " + cambio + " WHERE id = " + id);
            if (stmt.executeUpdate() != 0){
                func = true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException(ex);
        }
        return func;
    }
```

Así, y tengo más métodos.

Después también tengo unas clases auxiliares:

```
public class AccesoUsuario extends Conexion {

    private ResultSet rs;
    private Consulta cons;

    public AccesoUsuario() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        cons = new Consulta("*", "usuarios");
    }

    public ResultSet getListadoUsuarios()
    {
        try {
            rs = cons.recuperarTodo();
            return rs;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
           return null;
        }
    }

    public String validarRepartidor(String usu, String pass) throws SQLException{
        String msj = "Datos incorrectos";
        rs = getListadoRepartidores();
        while (rs.next()){
            String usuario = rs.getString("nomUsuario");
            String clave = rs.getString("password");
            if (usu.equals(usuario) && pass.equals(clave)){
                if (repartidorActivo(usu, pass)){
                    msj = "Sesión ya iniciada";
                    return msj;
                }
                msj = "Correcto";
                return msj;
            }
        }
        return msj;
    }

    public ResultSet getListadoRepartidores() {
        try {
            rs = cons.recuperar("rol = 'REPARTIDOR'");
            return rs;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
           return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean repartidorActivo(String usu, String pass) throws SQLException{
        boolean ret = false;
        rs = repartidoresLogeados();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String usuario = rs.getString("nomUsuario");
            String clave = rs.getString("password");
            if (usu.equals(usuario) && pass.equals(clave)){
                ret = true;
                return ret;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public ResultSet repartidoresLogeados() throws SQLException{
        try {
            rs = cons.recuperar("rol = 'REPARTIDOR' AND (estado = 'ACTIVO' OR estado = 'REPARTIENDO')");
            return rs;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Por ejemplo, les muestro el servlet que se encarga del login de los Repartidores.

```
@WebServlet(name = "RepartidoresLoginServlet", urlPatterns = {"/RepartidoresLoginServlet"})
public class RepartidoresLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String usuario = request.getParameter("txtUsu");
        String clave = request.getParameter("txtPass");

        try {
            AccesoUsuario accesoU = new AccesoUsuario();
            String aux = accesoU.validarRepartidor(usuario, clave);
            switch(aux){
                case "Correcto":
                    int id = repartidorLogeado(usuario, clave);
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    session.setAttribute("idUsu", id);
                    response.sendRedirect("ConsultaPedidosServlet");
                    break;
                case "Datos incorrectos":
                    request.setAttribute("msj", aux);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("repartidores/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    break;
                case "Sesión ya iniciada":
                    request.setAttribute("msj", aux);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("repartidores/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    break;
            }

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RepartidoresLoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }


    private int repartidorLogeado(String usu, String pass) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Consulta cons = new Consulta("*", "usuarios");
        cons.actualizar("estado = 'ACTIVO'", "nomUsuario = '" + usu + "' AND password = '" + pass + "'");

        ResultSet rs = cons.recuperar("nomUsuario = '" + usu + "' AND password = '" + pass + "'");
        int id = 0;
        if (rs.next())
            id = rs.getInt("id");
        return id;
    }
}
```

Donde y cómo debería cerrar las conexiones??
Gracias!!

Comment: hola . te recomiendo que el atributo private static Connection cnx = null; sea una variable local del metodo quedando asi en todos tus metodos Connection cnx = null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las conexiones si lo creas manualmente tienes que cerrar después de haberlos usados, pero en Java te recomiendo de usar un `DataSource` con un pool de conexiones para acceder bases de datos.

Si remplazas la creación de conexiones manuales con un `BasicDataSource` de apache commons, pides una conexión prestado a la fuente de data y cuando terminas devuelves la conexión llamando `close()` para ser reutilizado.

Asumiendo que te creaste un `BasicDataSource` como *Singleton* en el contexto de tu codigo, y lo llamaste `basicDataSource`, puedes en cualquier parte obtener una conexion valida como:

```
Connection con = basicDataSource.getConnection();
// haz con la conexión lo que quieras hacer
...
// luego lo devuelves al pool
con.close();
```

Trabajo con BBDD en Java no tiene que ser más complicado :)

Un ejemplo completo encuentras en [esta respuesta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46754/pool-de-conexiones-java/46762#46762)

Comment: El OP va creando `PreparedStatement` y ejecutándolos sin cerrarlos. Yo suelo usar un conector a BD con una conexión "singleton" que no cierro y creo `Statements` que cierro tras su ejecución para las operaciones con la BD ¿Qué diferencia hay entre lo que propones y lo que yo digo?

Comment: La diferencia principal es que tu trabajas con una conexión y mi código trabaja con un pool de conexiones flexibles, que (dependiente de la configuración) mantiene una cantidad de conexiones abiertas para prestarlos al usuario para sus consultas. Eso es el TLDR;, explicación más completa sería "demasiado amplio" para el contexto de esta pregunta.