# Copiar archivos, cambiarles el nombre y pasarlo a otra carpeta en java

Tags: java

estoy realizando un programa en java en donde quiero tener un orden de las imágenes con las que estoy trabajando y quiero tener una copia de esta, cambiarle el nombre y tenerla en una carpeta especifica. tengo el siguiente código.

```
 JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int seleccion = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

//Si el usuario, pincha en aceptar
        if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            try {
                //Seleccionamos el fichero
                File fichero = fc.getSelectedFile();
                if (fichero.exists()) {
                    File fdest = new File(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString() + "/" + conductor.getDni(), jTextField1.getText() + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fichero.getAbsolutePath()));
                    Files.move(fichero.toPath(), fdest.toPath()); //esta parte del codigo no funciona
//   FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(fichero, fdest); --> esta parte si me mueve el archivo pero no como necesito exactamente
                    if (fdest.exists()) {
                        Documentacion d = new Documentacion();
                        d.setConductor(conductor);
                        d.setDescripcion(jTextField1.getText());
                        d.setRuta(fdest.getAbsolutePath());
                        DocumentacionJpaController controller = new DocumentacionJpaController(emf);
                        controller.create(d);
                        cargarTabla(conductor);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("error no se pudo mover");
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AddDocumentos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
```

FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory funciona pero 
por ejemplo si tengo 
C:/a.jpg  y lo quiero mover a 
C:/micarpeta/cedula.jpg al ejecutar esa instruccion se crea lo siguiente
C:/micarpeta/cedula.jpg/a.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no necesitas la librería de Apache y sólo la vas a utilizar para copiar archivos (la debes tener para la solución de @StefanNolde), desde Java 1.7 existe un método nativo para hacer lo que pides:

```
Files.copy(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(origen),
       FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(destino),
       StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Así evitas tener que incluir una librería a tu proyecto si no te hacen falta.

Comment: Buen dato, estoy un poco acostumbrado de casi siempre tener commons en el BuildPath, ya por dependencias a otras bibliotecas de apache que uso mucho. :) No sabes por si acaso si hay una alternativa sin dependencias a `dbcp`o `c3p0` en las versiónes más recientes de Java?

Comment: @StefanNolde cuando he previsto una gran cantidad de conexiones he usado Hibernate y Spring. Cuando son aplicaciones con pocas conexiones he usado lo que te ponía en [mi comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49702/problema-al-cerrar-conexi%c3%b3n-bd-java/49709#comment87628_49709) a tu respuesta en otra pregunta y no hace falta usar las librerías que comentas. Cuando quieras podemos pasar a hablar del tema en el chat.

Comment: me malentendiste, pregunté si quizás hubieron añadido algo en la biblioteca del sistema en Java8 para pools. Si trabajo con frameworks, sé que puedo usar, la idéa fue que se puede hacer sin añadir dependencias. si no,

Answer (score 2):

Cambiar de nombre, mover, eliminar o copiar un archivo en Java

[Aqui](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/13/cambiar-de-nombre-mover-eliminar-o-copiar-un-archivo-en-java/)

La clase java.nio.file.Files, implementa una serie de métodos estáticos para las operaciones de manejo de ficheros(archivos), entre los cuales está el método move().

Utilizando este método, podemos escribir una función que mueve un archivo de un directorio a otro. El método move() recibe un argumento CopyOptions, con el que podemos especificar que sobrescribe el fichero de destino si ya existía.

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class MoverArchivoMove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path origenPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\carpeta1\\ejemplo1.jpg");
        Path destinoPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\carpeta2\\ejemplo1.jpg");

        try {
            Files.move(origenPath, destinoPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Copiar un archivo en Java

La clase java.nio.file.Files, implementa una serie de métodos estáticos para las operaciones de manejo de ficheros(archivos), entre los cuales está el método copy().

Utilizando este método, podemos escribir una función que copia un archivo en otro lado. El método copy() recibe un argumento CopyOptions, con el que podemos especificar que sobrescribe el fichero de destino si ya existía.

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class CopiarArchivo {

    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    public static void copiarArchivo(String origenArchivo, String destinoArchivo) {
        try {
            Path origenPath = Paths.get(origenArchivo);
            Path destinoPath = Paths.get(destinoArchivo);
            //sobreescribir el fichero de destino si existe y lo copia
            Files.copy(origenPath, destinoPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta con explicación y ejemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, tengo entendido que renombrando ficheros lo puedes hacer. Crea dos objetos del tipo File, el primero sería:

```
 f1 = new File("C:/a.jpg"),
```

y el segundo sería

```
 f2 = new File("C:/micarpeta/cedula.jpg");
```

luego tendrías que renombrarlo:

```
 f1.renameTo(f2)
```

Espero que sea la solución a tu problema.

Comment: al utilizar renameTo() me retorna falso y no lo realiza

Comment: ok, prueba así :                                                                                             Path FROM = Paths.get("direccion origen");
        Path TO = Paths.get("direccion destino");
        CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
          StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
          StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
        }; 
        Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);

Comment: Se presenta la siguiente excepción :  java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\personal\Documents\^B77B49C1A067117CC5E9D8DCB43F0A266A84079800AF5A9F71^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.jpg -> C:\Users\personal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ADTAXI\1082966509\cedula.jpg

Comment: Esa excepción da cuando no encuentra el archivo. Fijate si colocaste bien la ruta al archivo en el origen, o comenta como programaste esa parte así vemos que puede ser

Comment: el archivo al cual se esta copiando "TO" no existe, ¿debería crearlo primero antes de copiarlo?

Comment: Mira, el directorio que le pasas si debe existir, capaz por eso te da el error.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso que todavía se usa Java6 o anterior, se puede usar de `apache.commons`

```
File fuente = new File("ruta/a/fuente.jpg");
File destino = new File("ruta/a/otro/destino.jpg);
FileUtils.copyFile(fuente,destino);
```

Si usas `copyFileToDirectory` pasa lo esperado que Java asume que destino sería una carpeta y agrega el nuevo nombre.

Comment: gracias, el problema fue que utilice una vez el copyFile() pero al parecer por alguna razón me detectaba que el origen no existía

Comment: Desde Java 1.7 ya no hace falta usar la librería de apache si no la necesitas, quedando un código claro y rápido con el método `Files.copy`. He añadido otra respuesta con esto, aunque ya que te han aceptado la respuesta si añades esto la borraría.