# ¿Como puedo cerrar la conexión a mi base de datos?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Lo que pasa es que cuando ejecuto esta sentencia en mi base de datos se queda en estado **Sleep** y después de cierto tiempo me da el error de **Too many connections** debido a que hay varios registros en mi base de datos espero me puedan ayudar.

```
public ResultSet CuentaRegistros() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String sentencia = "SELECT count(*) FROM producto WHERE Cantidad <= Cantidad_Minima";
    PreparedStatement pst = c.getConnection().prepareStatement(sentencia);
    return pst.executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminando tu trabajo con la conexión tienes que cerrarla con `pst.close();`. Alternativamente puedes también llamar a `close()` al `ResultSet` despues que terminas trabajar con el:

```
ResultSet rs = CuentaRegistros();
// trabajar con el result set
rs.close(); // eso tambien te cierra los recursos abiertos para obtener este result set
```

Cuando te conectas a una BBDD, se usan recursos (conexiones, sockets) que son limitados. Sin cerrar la conexión después del uso, estos recursos del sistema nunca se liberan, hasta te sale el error que tienes demasiados conexiones abiertos. Tu escribiste un método que te genera una conexión y te devuelve un resultado. Para poder trabajar con el resultado necesitas dejar los recursos abiertos todavía, eso no te permite cerrar la conexión antes de devolver el resultado. Para facilitar lo que tu haces, el `ResultSet` implementa un método `close()` que no solamente cierra el resultado, pero también cierra todos los recursos vinculados (incluyendo la conexión).

Para evitar problemas con demasiados conexiones abiertas, te recomiendo un *Pool* de conexiónes. `BasicDataSource` de apache-commond-dbcp por ejemplo es una buena manera de manejar un pool de conexiones simple y estable. Más detalles sobre eso encuentras en [esta respuesta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49702/problema-al-cerrar-conexi%C3%B3n-bd-java/49709#49709)

Comment: Me pediste más explicaciones, te lo agrego a la respuesta.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, ahora me ha quedado mas claro y perdon por lo de publicar dos veces mi pregunta lo que pasa es que soy nuevo y quize explicar mas mi problema

Comment: Ningun drama, Puedes eliminar la otra pregunta, o se va cerrar por duplicado. Si recibiste una solución a tu problema, por favor acepta la respuesta que te daba la solución (con el tic abajo de la puntuación) y si sientes que esta o otra respuesta te sirvió o te parece útil, puedes votar en su favor.

Answer (score 3):

Buenas

Con la información que aportas no estoy muy seguro de que es cada cosa, pero, diría que deberías poder ejecutar un :

```
pst.close // Justo al terminar de trabajar con tu statement en la función
```

El problema es, que si cierras el statement, ya no podrás trabajar sobre el resultset. Sin más datos no se muy bien que más decirte.

Saludos

Comment: el problema es que si hago lo que tu dices me sale el error de unreachable statement pero si me pudieses ayudar un poco mas te puedo facilitar la informacion que necesites

Comment: Efectivamente, no estoy seguro de si se puede hacer de una forma más limpia, pero tal vez debería replantearte el funcionamiento para dejar de trabajar con funciones que usen ResultSets (puesto estos dejan de ser accesibles al cerrarse la conexión).

Quizás , podrías crear una función diferente, sin el return y hacer un método que simplemente obtenga la información y (en caso de que necesites trabajar con ella en otros lados) guardarla en un tipo o estructura clásica (Arraylist, pe).

Comment: @RoberthTorres Al final pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: Todavía no, estoy en eso.

Comment: @RoberthTorres Qué problema estás teniendo ?

Comment: Lo que me pasa es que cada vez que cargo los datos de my BD a un jtable las conexiones se quedan en modo sleep y despues de cierto tiempo me lanza un error de too many conections

Comment: @RoberthTorres Como ya te he comentado, lo que creo que está ocurriendo es que el pst.close() haciendo que se te acumulen las peticiones sin cerrar.

Esto se puede afrontar de bastante maneras, pero una forma sería convertir esa función en un método , guardar el resultado haciendo Resulset rs = executeQuery  . Posteriormentr trabajar con esos datos para hacer lo que quieras y, finalmente, hacer el close. Eso haría que cada vez que mandas una petición esta termine cerrandose al terminar de trabajar. Actualizaré ahora mi respuesta con un ejemplo.

Comment: @RoberthTorres si recibiste "Unreachable Statement" probablemente agregaste código despies de un `return`. Con eso tu IDE te señala que colocaste código que nunca se va ejecutar, porque lo colocaste en una parte a donde no llegas, porque devias antes por un `break`o `return` o otro control de flujo.

Answer (score 2):

Tambien puedes usar si usas java 1.7 o superior el try con recursos, asi te olvidas de hacer .close() java lo hará por ti.

Te dejo la documentación oficial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

El último trozo de código tiene un ejemplo concreto de una query

Answer (score 1):

como dicen los compañeros y como tienes planteada la pregunta pocas salidas te quedan.
La más lógica es que hagas todos tus cálculos, métodos, operaciones ... antes de cerrar para no quedarte pillado.

```
conexion.close();
```

yo como idea me crearía un método cerrarConexion();

```
public void cerrarConexion() throws ConnectionException {
try {
       conexion.close();
}catch (SQLException  sqle) {
    throw new ConnectionException("Ha ocurrido un error al intentar cerrar la conexion con la BBDD. Error:" + sqle.getMessage());


    }
}
```

asi podemos calcular alguna excepción con los datos e integras el método cada vez que cierres, aunque sin verlo bien con tu exposición de la pregunta.

Comment: creo que algo más fina está y para seguir trabajando es buen camino.