# Tengo un problema al cerrar la conexión a mi base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, mvc

Bueno lo que pasa es que esto desarrollando un programa y dentro de ese programa necesito cargar datos de mi base de datos y aqui es donde tengo el problema ya que al ejecutar una sentencia las conexiones se quedan en modo sleep, por lo que despues de un tiempo de usar la aplicacion me genera el error de too many connections.
Estoy trabajando con la arquitectura de MVC (Modelo - Vista - Controlador) y he divido los paquetes en DAT, BL y GUI.
Ahora bien necesito que me ayuden a determinar como cerrar mis conexiones de manera correcta para evitar que las sentencias se queden en modo sleep.

Aquí esta la parte del paquete DAT que es donde ejecuto la sentencia que me servirá para cargar los datos de my BD a mi jtable.

```
public ResultSet ConsultarxNombre(String nombre) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    String Sentencia = "SELECT DISTINCT dv.Id_Venta, c.Deuda, v.Total_Venta, v.Valor_Cancelado, v.Fecha,c.Nombres "
            + "FROM clientes c, detalle_venta dv, venta v "
            + "WHERE c.Cedula = dv.Cedula AND v.Id_Venta = dv.Id_Venta AND v.Valor_Cancelado<v.Total_Venta AND c.Nombres = ? ORDER BY c.Nombres Asc, dv.Id_Venta";
    PreparedStatement ps = c.getConnection().prepareStatement(Sentencia);
    ps.setString(1, nombre);
    return ps.executeQuery();
}
```

si necesitan mas informacion me lo dicen y yo les facilitaré dicha informacion. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Después de trabajar con el `ResultSet` que obtienes de tu método, tienes que cerrar la conexión. Eso puedes hacer llamando `close()` al `ResultSet`.

```
ResultSet rs = ConsultarxNombre(nombre);
// trabajar con rs
rs.close(); // eso cierra todos recursos generados para obtener rs
```

Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62909/como-puedo-cerrar-la-conexi%C3%B3n-a-mi-base-de-datos/62925#62925) para más informaciones.

Comment: Podrías explicarme un poco mas como hacer lo que me recomiendas, lo que pasa es que todavía soy novato, te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Para empezar no deberías repetir la misma pregunta, menos cuando ya recibiste respuestas. Si quieres que te explico más, preguntame en tu pregunta original que hiciste hace 3h. Alla en mi respuesta encuentras más informaciónes.