# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de usar conexiones y cerrar conexiones?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqlconnector.jar

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual utilizo **MySQL** para almacenar los datos, al momento de realizar la conexión con la base de datos me surge la duda de cual es la mejor manera de cerrar la conexión con la base de datos o de si es posible mantener la conexión abierta y cerrar al final de la ejecución de la aplicación

Si realizo un método que se encargue de cerrar cada ves que realizo la operación o de si puede haber mejor manera de usar la conexión para evitar **abrir** y **cerrar** la conexión con cada operación que realizo con la base de datos

El método que utilizo para conectar es el siguiente

```
public Connection conectarMySQL() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        try {
            //Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            //+ "user=" + username + "&password=" + password);
            // Do something with the Connection
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error con la cocnexión a base de datos", "Error de conexión", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle the error
    }

    return conn;
}
```

De ejemplo para realizar algún `SELECT` o `INSERT` utilizo un método parecido a esto, en lo cual como idea creo un método aparte que solo me sirve para cerrar la conexión.

```
public void consulta() {
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        stmt = conectarMySQL().createStatement();
        if (stmt.execute("SELECT nombre FROM alumnos")) {
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            rs.next();
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            } // ignore

            rs = null;
        }

        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            } // ignore

            stmt = null;
        }
        cerrarConexion();
    }
}
```

El metodo que tengo pensado para cerrar conexión es el siguiente

```
public void cerrarConexion(){
    try {
        conectarMySQL().close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al cerrar conexión = "+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Es una aplicación de escritorio, cliente-servidor, web ó móvil?

Comment: aplicación de escritorio.

Comment: Crea y cerra la conexion cada vez que la uses. El pool de conexiones se encarga de eso tranquilamente y no es algo que afecte a tu sistema.

Comment: @gbianchi entonces lo que tengo implementado ahí esta correcto ? o es correcto hacer eso ?

Comment: @gbianchi El problema es que no está usando un *pool*, está creando una conexión nueva para cada consulta

Comment: Vos sos el experto @PabloLozano.. en C# los objetos se encargan de mantener el pool, pero aca es tu territorio...

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46754/pool-de-conexiones-java/46762#46762

Comment: @PabloLozano Por lo que veo en el enlace que mandas, básicamente dice que no existe forma correcta de cerrarlo, y por lo que veo cada acción que realice tengo que cerrar la conexión para evitar problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a aclarar algunos conceptos:

#### Las conexiones a la base de datos

Abrir y cerrar conexiones a una base de datos son operaciones *pesadas*, sobre todo para la propia base de datos. Cada conexión tiene una serie de buffers y otros recursos asociados que hay que crear. El costo en memoria no es pequeño, por eso la mayoría de las veces no suele haber más de unas decenas de conexiones activas y se suelen reutilizar.

#### Las instancias de `java.sql.Connection`

Hemos de tener en cuenta que java.sql.Connection es una **interfaz**, no una clase. Por tanto no tiene por qué ser igual una conexión creada manualmente:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Que una obtenida a través de un pool de conexiones ( o *datasource*):

```
Connection c= myDatasource.getConnection();
```

Un indicio de que no son lo mismo es la falta de parámetros: un *datasource* es un gestor de conexiones, al que delegas la creación y manejo de las mismas. Cuando pides una conexión, lo más probable es que ésta ya estuviese abierta y se esté reutilizando. Si todas las abiertas están siendo usadas, es posible que se cree una nueva o, si has llegado al límite (hay varios threads usando conexiones a la vez), te toque esperar a que alguna quede libre.

¿Cómo se liberan? Cuando llamas a `c.close()`. Recuerda, `Connection` es una interfaz, la implementación de la misma dependerá del driver y/o del gestor de conexiones. Los gestores rara vez cierran (cortan) una conexión *real* con la base de datos a causa de lo costoso que es crearla de nuevo, lo normal es que la declaren *no-en-uso* (libre) para que se pueda usar en cualquier otro momento.

Normalmente, si una conexión lleva mucho tiempo (segundos) sin usarse, es probable que se libere automáticamente, pero en una aplicación web que recibe cientos o miles de peticiones por hora, lo normal es pedir la conexión, hacer la consulta y liberarla en unas pocas centésimas de segundo (a menos que la consulta sea compleja y la respuesta de la base de datos necesite mucho tiempo para ser generada, claro) para poder ser reutilizada.

Como ejemplo popular pero sencillo de gestor de conexiones tenemos [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/), y un ejemplo de configuración es [éste](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization). Es el *connection pool* por defecto de las aplicaciones creadas con Spring Boot, lo que lo hace muy popular.