# Pool de conexiones en Java y SQL: ¿Puedo llamar varias veces a createDataSource() manteniendo el mismo pool?

Tags: java, sql

¿Puedo llamar varias veces a la siguiente línea manteniendo el mismo pool de conexiones?

```
DataSource dataSource = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(propiedades);
```

O debería guardarlo en una variable estática para compartir el mismo pool en todos las solicitudes durante la ejecución del programa?

En caso de tener que conservar el resultado obtenido en *dataSource*, cómo podría conservarlo de manera correcta durante toda la ejecución del programa sin tener problemas de concurrencia?

Comment: Échale un vistazo al patrón de diseño singleton https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4418071/effective-ways-to-implement-and-use-the-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: El diseño singleton no es recomendado en casi ningún caso. Esta esta [respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507687/should-a-db-connection-be-a-singleton) explica un poco acerca de este tipo de diseños.

Comment: La respuesta dependerá de tu arquitectura, si en un sólo lugar utilizas la conexión pool, no es necesario hacerla estático, de lo contrario sería lo ideal. Recuerda siempre liberar tus conexiones pool. [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46754/pool-de-conexiones-java?rq=1) podría ayudarte un poco